# default tile in absence of a tile in osmdroid offline map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, offline, osmdroid

In openstreet osmdroid offline map project , i want to show a default image tile (saying zoom out to see here or tile not avaliable ) in place of null Tile  ,if some combination of lat long and zoom level does not have tile .
i have checked this handleTile method of org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay class( http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.osmdroid/osmdroid-android/4.0/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/TilesOverlay.java#TilesOverlay.0mLoadingBackgroundColor) .
i am confused ,how to get it done .

Thank you .
.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll want to go right to the source.
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

I've actually attempted to do exactly what you're asking for and couldn't get a positive result. I think you just want to return a default tile that has a red X or something like that when the tile is null. The problem is a bit more complicated due to multiple tile providers (assets, sdcard storage, online, etc). The tile overlay is definitely the place to go. If you get it working, open a pull request ;)